# Windows Media Player plays only audio from MPG 320x240

Tags: windows-7, video, windows-media-player, video-codecs

My OS is Windows 7 Ultimate 64 Bit. I have a few video files in the format of MPEG. Some are 320x240 frame size  and other are 720x576.

Both are .MPG extensions.

The default Windows Media Player (I could not figure out the Version) plays 720 seamlessly. However when I play MPG that is 320 only audio is heard. Video is blank.

This is strange as I think default Windows Media Player should be able to play MPG with lower resolution without any add on.

I tried a third party codecs like media.player.codec.pack.v4.5.2.setup.exe but it did not help.

I am not too sure why this issue occurs and what's the fix now.

I do have VLC player and it has no issues playing both these types. However I would prefer to fix the issue with Windows Media Player as it's my favorite app.

Also just note that I have Windows XP in VMWare Player Virtual Machine. The same MPG file (320x240) is played by WMP v9 in XP seamlessly without any issues.

Update

---

I installed K-Lite_Codec_Pack_1475_Mega.exe but it did not help.

Comment: As a troubleshooting step,  get the program Mediainfo it runs via command line. And do `mediainfo blah.mpg`, it will tell you 3 things. The Container, Video Codec,  and Audio Codec.  Maybe the ones that don't run are distinct from the ones that do.U could use ffmpeg to reencode it. `ffmpeg -i blah.mpg -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac myblah.mp4` I don't know a good audio codec but  could try changing libfaac to libfdk_aac  or to libmp3lame.I don't really understand codecs and ffmpeg but that may help. I've used ffmpeg for years, though it always baffles me, but I sometimes find lines that work

Comment: Also bear in mind with ffmpeg a codec that might be recommended one year, the next year people say is not good, but anyhow.

Comment: Finally I fixed it! I will re-verify this and after confirming that I have not broken anything else in the process, shall attempt to answer my own question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the question, I am still not clear why WMP failed to play MPEG1 MPG 320x240 file. This is one of the oldest formats and should have been supported.

I thought just installing K-Lite_Codec_Pack_1475_Mega might fix the problem, but it did not. Then I decided to explore if there are any settings in the K-Lite codec pack.

Here's how I fixed it. Just taking the liberty to post it as an answer just in case anyone else comes across this issue ever.

Go to K-Lite Codec Pack --> Codec Tweak Tool from the start menu.

Windows 7 Preferred decoders de-select Microsoft for MPEG1 and select LAV under both 32 as well as 64 Bit. Apply & Close

Go to MS Codec Tweaks and Disable Microsoft DTV-DVD Video Decoder.

As I am not Codec Expert, can not explain why but this fixed the issue.

Here are the screenshots of the fix and also of the issue and working video thereafter.

[image]

[image]

Blank Video when Microsoft default is used.

[image]

Proper AV after changing settings.

[image]